# 404 error when submitting form with empty field

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a php page with several html forms. When a submit button is pressed while a text field is empty, I want an error to appear when the page refreshes, but instead I'm getting a 404 error. What's weird is I don't get a 404 if the fields are not empty.

This is the code for /books/index.php and the 404 error states `The requested URL /books/index.php was not found on this server.`

```
<?php
//Books

//Variables on refresh:
//  $_POST['pgNum']         //Page number
//  $_POST['id']            //If page is being updated. ID of the book being updated
//  $_POST['newBook']       //If new book is added. Name of the new book
//  $_GET['empty']          //If the form to add a new book was submitted with 1 or more empty fields. 
                            //Equals 1 if book name is empty, 2 if page number is empty, and 3 if both are empty.
//  $_GET['emptyPgNum']     //If an update button was pressed with no page number in the corresponding field,
                            //this variable will exist on the redirect


require_once 'connection.php';          //Function to connect to MySQL database
require_once 'queryFunctions.php';      //Functions for sending MySQL queries


if(isset($_GET['emptyPgNum'])) {
    //Reload from submission with an empty page number field
    echo '<font color="red">Missing page number</font><br>';
}

//Check if this page loaded from a successful form submission
if(isset($_POST['id'])) {           //If page update was submitted
    //Check for empty form field
    if(empty($_POST['pgNum'])) {
        //Empty page number field. Redirect with error
        unset($_POST);
        header('Location: index.php?emptyPgNum=3');
    }           

    //Update the pageNumber field and redirect back to index.php
    $conn = getConnection();
    $update = "UPDATE Books SET pageNumber={$_POST['pgNum']}
               WHERE id={$_POST['id']}";
    booleanQuery($conn, $update);
    mysqli_close($conn);

    header('Location: index.php');
} else if(isset($_POST['newBook'])) {           //If new book is being added

    //Check if any form fields were submitted empty
    if(empty($_POST['newBook']) && empty($_POST['pgNum'])) {
        //Both fields empty
        unset($_POST);
        header('Location: index.php?empty=3');
    } else if(empty($_POST['newBook'])) {
        //Empty book name
        unset($_POST);          
        header('Location: index.php?empty=1');
    } else if(empty($_POST['pgNum'])) {
        //Empty page number
        unset($_POST);
        header('Location: index.php?empty=2');
    }

    //Insert the new book into the database and redirect back to index.php
    $conn = getConnection();
    $update = "INSERT INTO Books (name, pageNumber) VALUES(\"{$_POST['newBook']}\", {$_POST['pgNum']});";
    booleanQuery($conn, $update);
    mysqli_close($conn);

    header('Location: index.php');
} else {            
    //No POST data

    //HTML to add page title
    ?>
    <head>
    <title>Books</title>
    </head>
    <?php

    //Retrieve the list of books
    $conn = getConnection();
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM Books ORDER BY id;';
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if(mysqli_errno($conn)) {                               //Display error if query failed
        echo "<br>Query error:" . mysqli_error($conn) . "<br>" . mysqli_errno($conn) . "<br>";
        exit();
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body OnLoad="document.form1.pgNum.focus()">        <!--Set cursor focus to the first form field-->

<?php
    //For each book in the database, show it's current page number and create a form for submitting a page update    
    $formNumber = 1;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "\"{$row['name']}\" page number: {$row['pageNumber']}<br>";
    echo '<form action="index.php" method="post" name="form' . $formNumber . '">';
    echo 'New Page Number: <input type="text" name="pgNum">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $row['id'] . '">';
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Update">';
    echo '</form><br>';
    $formNumber++;
}
echo "<br>";

//Check if this page loaded from an unsuccessful form submission
if(isset($_GET['empty'])) {
    //$_GET['empty'] equals 1 if book name is empty, 2 if page number is empty, and 3 if both are empty.
    switch($_GET['empty']) {
        case 1:
            echo '<font color="red">Missing book name</font><br>';
            break;
        case 2:
            echo '<font color="red">Missing page number</font><br>';
            break;
        case 3:
            echo '<font color="red">Empty fields</font><br>';
            break;
    }
}
?>

<!--Create a form for adding a new book to the database-->
<form method="post">
New Book: <input type="text" name="newBook"><br>
Page Number: <input type="text" name="pgNum">
<input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Edit: I used to have the full qualified http:// address in all the header lines and still had the same error. I changed them to the shortened versions during debugging.

Comment: does the page /books/index.php really exist? is there any redirection? url rewritting ?

Comment: You're looking at the contents of the index.php file I put in the books folder. The only other thing I have in there is a couple of php files that have MySQL related functions (no redirects or anything like that)